# Error while sending attachments via Openerp 7 'Social Network' app but works fine while sending normal message

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

I am using OpenERP 7. I get following error when i try to send attachments to other users via Social Network app but works fine while sending normal message to other users! Thanks in advance!

```
Client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 204, in dispatch
    response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1125, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(req, model, method, args, {})
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1113, in _call_kw
    return getattr(req.session.model(model), method)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 42, in proxy
    result = self.proxy.execute_kw(self.session._db, self.session._uid, self.session._password, self.model, method, args, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
    result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 103, in send
    raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.ustr(e), formatted_info)


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 89, in send
    return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 188, in execute_kw
    return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 131, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 197, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 185, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/purchase/purchase.py", line 1223, in send_mail
    return super(mail_compose_message, self).send_mail(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/sale/sale.py", line 996, in send_mail
    return super(mail_compose_message, self).send_mail(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/account/account_invoice.py", line 1790, in send_mail
    return super(mail_compose_message, self).send_mail(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/email_template/wizard/mail_compose_message.py", line 80, in send_mail
    return super(mail_compose_message, self).send_mail(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/mail/wizard/mail_compose_message.py", line 259, in send_mail
    msg_id = active_model_pool.message_post(cr, uid, [res_id], type='comment', subtype=subtype, context=context, **post_values)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/mail/mail_thread.py", line 1052, in message_post
    ir_attachment.write(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, filtered_attachment_ids, {'res_model': model, 'res_id': thread_id}, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/base_calendar/crm_meeting.py", line 160, in write
    return super(ir_attachment, self).write(cr, uid, ids, vals, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/document/document.py", line 129, in write
    return super(document_file, self).write(cr, uid, ids, vals, context)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_attachment.py", line 268, in write
    self.check(cr, uid, ids, 'write', context=context, values=vals)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/document/document.py", line 76, in check
    return super(document_file, self).check(cr, uid, ids, mode='read', context=context, values=values)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_attachment.py", line 208, in check
    mids = self.pool.get(model).exists(cr, uid, mids)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'exists'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug. The reason being that context is not passed correctly when you click on the "Compose New Message" button or other send message buttons. The bug has been reported. They should be working on it by now.

Comment: If for example www.abcdwxy.com is my website and OpenERP can be accessed via www.abcdwxy.com:8069 then where can i access files of OpenERP so that i can change its css and other things!

Comment: It depends on your OS. Windows installation is in your Program files. For Linux Ubuntu, You can check in the addons folder in /usr/local/lib/pythonX.y/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_xxxxxxxx-pyX.x.egg/openerp/ Try not to modify the css files directly. Write a module that will do the css, js, ... modifications in the form of extension.